# Deep learning model not giving predictions as input layer is incompatible

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, input

bELOW IS A SIMPLE MODEL FOR IMAGE CLASSIFICATION OF HAND GESTURE RECOGNITION using Kaggle [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/gti-upm/leapgestrecog)
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""kaggle_dataset_code.ipynb

```
Automatically generated by Colaboratory.

Original file is located at
    https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1kfj2kPVrioXlWX_CDDOGEfxlwMUj5vs6
"""

!pip install kaggle

#You can download the kaggl.json file from your kaggle account. We are going to upload the kaggle.json file.
from google.colab import files
files.upload()

#making kaggle directory as kaggle website has guided.
!mkdir -p ~/.kaggle
!cp kaggle.json ~/.kaggle/

#Giving specical permissions to the kaggle.json file.
!chmod 600  ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json

downloading the kaggle dataset from the website by copying the API token 
!kaggle datasets download -d gti-upm/leapgestrecog

#Unzip the dataset
zip_data_path = "/content/leapgestrecog.zip"
from zipfile import ZipFile
file_name = "leapgestrecog.zip"

with ZipFile(file_name,'r') as zip:
  zip.extractall()
  print("done")

import cv2

image_data = []
CATEGORIES = ["01_palm", '02_l','03_fist','04_fist_moved','05_thumb','06_index','07_ok','08_palm_moved','09_c','10_down']
IMG_SIZE = 50
import os
unzipped_data_path = "/content/leapgestrecog/leapGestRecog/"
print(os.listdir(unzipped_data_path))

for dr in os.listdir(unzipped_data_path):
    for category in CATEGORIES:
      class_index = CATEGORIES.index(category)
      path = os.path.join(unzipped_data_path, dr, category)
      for image in os.listdir(path):
        image_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, image), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        image_data.append([cv2.resize(image_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)), class_index])

#image data of a 19000th image
image_data[19000]

import random
random.shuffle(image_data)
input_data = []
label = []
for X, y in image_data:
  input_data.append(X)
  label.append(y)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # for plotting
plt.figure(1, figsize=(10,10))
for i in range(1,10):
    plt.subplot(3,3,i)
    plt.imshow(image_data[i][0], cmap='hot')
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.title(CATEGORIES[label[i]][3:])
plt.show()

import numpy as np
input_data = np.array(input_data)
label = np.array(label)
input_data = input_data/255.0

import keras

label = keras.utils.to_categorical(label, num_classes=10,dtype='i1')
label[0]

input_data.shape = (-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(input_data, label, test_size = 0.3, random_state=0)

from keras.layers import Conv2D, Activation, MaxPool2D, Dense, Flatten, Dropout
model = keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3,3), input_shape = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))


model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
             optimizer = 'rmsprop',
             metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.summary()

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 7, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=128)
print(score)

model.save("kaggle_dataset_model.h5")
```

but i get the similar following error no matter which model i try

**ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_2 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape [None, 50, 50, 3]**

The code where I want the model to make predictions is below

```
Automatically generated by Colaboratory.

Original file is located at
    https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PWDO7aYA6Lhl9FgdgMHh8fj-vlLF_mTw
"""

from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np

# dimensions of our images
img_width = 50
img_height = 50
# load the model we saved
model = load_model('KaggleModelLeapGesture.h5')
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

from google.colab import files
from keras.preprocessing import image

uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
 
  # predicting images
  path = fn
  img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(50, 50))
  x = image.img_to_array(img)
  x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

  images = np.vstack([x])
  classes = model.predict(images, batch_size=10)
  print(fn)
  print(classes)
```

Comment: You have to put code in the question itself as text, not as external links.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I have included the code can you identify the error now?

Comment: Your training images were loaded as grayscale images, but in your code to make predictions you are not doing that, I recommend that you use the same code that you used to load training images for your prediction images.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy thanks for pointing out.I have changed the line in testing code from 
img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(50, 50))
to
img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(50, 50),color_mode='grayscale')
but in case of palm picture i get following predictions.

[[3.7882763e-19 8.0912974e-09 5.0884543e-19 1.0000000e+00 8.5896360e-27
  3.1044631e-12 3.7023463e-13 2.7725446e-12 1.5224544e-20 6.1532958e-19]]
Can you please guide

Comment: I am not sure what kind of guide you need, you have your predictions so seems the problem is solved.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy i am a beginner in deep learning usually it is 1 or 0 in case of prediction what does a value like 5.0884543e-19  mean in these classes.

Answer (score 0):

As [Dr. Snoopy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/349130/dr-snoopy) suggested, the model is trained on Grey scale images, but you are trying to predict on RGB image. Kindly use the grey scale version of the image.

Coming to your next question regarding the predictions, the last layer of your model is having `model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))` - that means you have 10 class to be predicted and as you have used `softmax` function, it gives the probability of the image belonging to these 10 different classes. The sum of all the probability will be equal to 1.

Comment: is there a way to tell the highest prediction so to tell image belongs to which category